# Why for arbitrary X in a plane, vector $PX = \lambda (PQ) + \mu (PR)$?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

In constructing a plane equation V in 3D, we should know three points, for example, $P(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $Q(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, and $R(x_3, y_3, z_3)$.

Why for arbitrary point $X$ in $V$, vector $PX  = \lambda (PQ) + \mu (PR)$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are real numbers?.

as far as I know, not every vector can be a linear combination of other vectors

Comment: Make $P$ the origin, draw coordinate axes and unit vectors. Any vector on the plane can be represented as a linear combination of unit vectors, right? Then express unit vectors via linear combination of $PQ$ and $PR$.

Comment: That’s only true if $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are not colinear.